# Spring boot java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : could not find class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.securityAutoConfiguration]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, pom.xml

1. Starting the application
2. The following profiles are active: ...
3. Application runs failed

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : could not find class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.securityAutoConfiguration]

at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:334) - [spring-core-5.3.20 jar : 5.3.20]

Comment: Could you please provide:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Share your pom.xml and all details which can help reader to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your build.gradle (or pom.xml): `compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I updated the spring boot starter parent version to 2.5.8 and it is working fine. I think the issue is my spring boot starter parent version was not compatible with version >2.6.0.